# oracle: Error: NJS-012: encountered invalid bind data type in parameter 2

Tags: node.js, oracle11g, node-oracledb

I am inserting new users into `users` table in `Oracle db` but encountering this error, 
`oracle: Error: NJS-012: encountered invalid bind data type in parameter 2` and when i have looked at the parameter being indicated, i see no problem !

```
function storedProcs() {
this.SP_USER_ADD_USER = {
    name: 'sp_user_adduser',
    params: {
        username    :  {val: null, type: dbParams.STRING, dir : dbParams.BIND_IN},
        password    :  {val: null, type: dbParams.STRING, dir : dbParams.BIND_IN},
        salt        :  {val: null, type: dbParams.STRING, dir : dbParams.BIND_IN},
        userTypeId  :  {val: null, type: dbParams.NUMBER, dir : dbParams.BIND_IN},
        isActive    :  {val: null, type: dbParams.NUMBER, dir : dbParams.BIND_IN},
        isTeller    :  {val: null, type: dbParams.NUMBER, dir : dbParams.BIND_IN},
        userLoginIpAuthTypeId       :  {val: null, type: dbParams.NUMBER, dir : dbParams.BIND_IN},
        userLoginIp :  {val: null, type: dbParams.STRING, dir : dbParams.BIND_IN},
        forceChangePassword         :  {val: null, type: dbParams.STRING, dir : dbParams.BIND_IN},
        customerId  :  {val: null, type: dbParams.NUMBER, dir : dbParams.BIND_IN},
        userId      :  {val: null, type: dbParams.NUMBER, dir : dbParams.BIND_OUT},
        errorMsg    :  {val: null, type: dbParams.STRING, dir : dbParams.BIND_OUT}
    }
    }
    }
```

``

``

```
   oracleDbAssist.getConnection(function(err,conn){
        if(err){
            console.log('error: - getConnection ' + JSON.stringify(err));
            return;
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
            session.newUser = myData[i];
            var sp = new StoredProcs().SP_USER_ADD_USER;
            sp.params.username.val = session.newUser.userName;
            sp.params.salt.val = util.generateSalt();
            sp.params.password.val = util.hash(session.newUser.password, sp.params.salt.val);
            sp.params.userTypeId.val = session.newUser.userTypeId;
            sp.params.isActive.val = session.newUser.isActive;
            sp.params.isTeller.val = session.newUser.isTeller;
            sp.params.forceChangePassword.val = session.newUser.forceChangePassword == 0 ? '0' : '1';
            sp.params.customerId.val = session.newUser.customerId;
            sp.params.userLoginIpAuthTypeId.val = session.newUser.userLoginIpAuthTypeId;
            sp.params.userLoginIp.val = session.newUser.userLoginIp;
            console.log('sp: ' + JSON.stringify(sp));
        oracleDbAssist.executeSqlWithConn(sp,true,conn, function(err,result){
            if(err){
                console.log('error:- executeSqlWithConn ' + err);
                return;
            }

            console.log('New user added: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
        });
        }
});
```

Below is the output from `console.log('sp: ' + JSON.stringify(sp));`
 Looking more closely at console output, no invalid data type is found.

``

```
sp: {
"name":"sp_user_adduser",
"params":{
"username":{"val":"200216","type":"STRING","dir":"BIND_IN"},
"password":{"val":"e64b580d65b34219826a1a89fc85dc8e17b97f59","type":"STRING","dir":"BIND_IN"},
"salt":{"val":"895909","type":"STRING","dir":"BIND_IN"},
"userTypeId":{"val":3,"type":"NUMBER","dir":"BIND_IN"},
"isActive":{"val":1,"type":"NUMBER","dir":"BIND_IN"},
"isTeller":{"val":0,"type":"NUMBER","dir":"BIND_IN"},
"userLoginIpAuthTypeId":{"val":1,"type":"NUMBER","dir":"BIND_IN"},
"userLoginIp":{"val":null,"type":"STRING","dir":"BIND_IN"},
"forceChangePassword":{"val":"1","type":"STRING","dir":"BIND_IN"},
"customerId":{"val":null,"type":"NUMBER","dir":"BIND_IN"},
"userId":{"val":null,"type":"NUMBER","dir":"BIND_OUT"},
"errorMsg":{"val":null,"type":"STRING","dir":"BIND_OUT"}}
}
```

``

i am now encountering this error after execution, `oracle: Error: NJS-012: encountered invalid bind data type in parameter 2`.

Any help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show us the output from `console.log('sp: ' + JSON.stringify(sp));`?

Comment: @ Dan McGhan, thanks and i have updated the post by adding that output.

Comment: Why are the `type` values strings like `"NUMBER"` instead of the constant values like 2010? Ditto the values of `dir`?  (BTW, the type constant values changed between node-oracledb 3.1.2 and 4.0)

Comment: @ChristopherJones when used ``"oracledb": "^3.1.2"`` and  ``node-v8.11.3-x64.msi    ``, the error is gone and the expected result is returned from db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the DB_TYPE_* constants. From the doc:

> These values indicate the Oracle Database type shown in extended
>   metadata for queries and REF CURSORS, and also shown for DbObject
>   types.

You can use the 3.1.2 Node-oracledb Type Constants:
https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-312-node-oracledb-type-constants

> Constants for execute() bind parameter type property, for the
>   createLob() type parameter, for the Lob type property, for
>   fetchAsBuffer, for fetchAsString and fetchInfo, and for extended
>   metadata.

Keep in mind that you don't need to specify the type with "in" binds because they all have default mappings based on the JS type. https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-201-in-bind-parameters

Comment: Sorry for the delay but it already helped me fix my issue. thanks